# What permission do I need to give a SQL Server login so that they can query sys.sql_modules?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

The SQL login has server roles public and db_creator. It has the server as a securable and has the Connect SQL permission. I used the command below to give it the VIEW SERVER STATE permission, but when I query the `sys.sql_modules` table it doesn't return data in the definition column. What permission do I need to give it so that it can read this column?

```
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO User1
```

**Problem:**

```
sys.sql_modules

object_id       definition
----------------------------------------
12345           NULL
67899           NULL
```

[image]

**Desired output:**

```
sys.sql_modules

object_id       definition
----------------------------------------
12345           CREATE VIEW dbo.View1...
67899           CREATE VIEW dbo.View2...
```

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @DaleK it takes a while to construct a table diagram using text so I figured it would be faster and provide more detail if I just use an image.

Comment: Faster for you, but harder for everyone else. What I have quoted is site policy, not my opinion. For what its worth, I can't read the data in your images - so they are unless for me.

Comment: @DaleK seems like a pretty archaic rule. They should review that.

Comment: Hmmm, well if you don't care that many of us can't even read it...

Comment: I don't think we really need an image to see that the values in the columns are all NULL anyway - you can just tell us that.

Comment: @DaleK not sure how many people it would affect. I never have any problems with images and I prefer reading questions and answers on this site with images because it gives me more context. But if this affects other people, sorry about that - I've written a table definition in text.

Comment: @MartinSmith agreed, but the other day my question got closed because I didn't provide an "example of the problem" (shrugs)

Comment: Regarding your actual question have you seen this? https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/260755/3690

Comment: @MartinSmith ohhh ok that was it. I had tried `VIEW DEFINITION` earlier but I guess I applied it to only one DB. I thought it would apply to all. I just applied it to my target DB and it works now. Thanks!

Comment: @whatin1992 is [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) enough reasons for you?

Comment: @DaleK yea I followed that post. I didn't post any images of code, that's annoying. I posted an image of the intended result in my dataabse. An image of my table shows more context than just showing two columns where one of them is null.

Comment: But yea I agree that when your phone can't load an image, that's pretty annoying too

Comment: The post applies to **DATA**, **ERRORS** && **CODE** - not just code. The image you provided, gives no additional information to data provided as text.

Comment: There are plenty of tools out there for converting data to Markdown tables, e.g.: [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). File > Paste table data, click Preview... profit!

Comment: @AlwaysLearning oh wow that's awesome! Yea the table generator would make that wayyyy less annoying to write out

Answer (score 0):

In order to query `sys.sql_modules`, the login needs to have `VIEW DEFINITION` permission on the database objects whose definition they want to see. To grant `VIEW DEFINITION` permission, you can use the following syntax:

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON [object] TO [login];
```

Replace `[object]` with the name of the object (such as a stored procedure or view) and `[login]` with the name of the SQL Server login that you want to grant permission to.

If you want to grant `VIEW DEFINITION` permission to all objects in a database, you can use the following syntax:

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO login;
```